# Using curl in a Windows Universal App

Tags: c++, c, windows, curl, uwp

I want to use curl in a Windows Universal App (x64).

I managed to get it working, but I had to use a workaround that seems hackish, and I want to confirm that it is needed.

**TL;DR** - I had to add an `#include <winsock2.h>` statement before the `#include <curl\curl.h>` statement, to get it to work. I want to know if it’s truly needed on UWP.

I built curl with openssl by following the curl install guide [here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html]). I created a blank universal app in Visual Studio 2015 update 3, and added curl and openssl binaries and includes in the appropriate places. Then added a `#include <curl\curl.h>` at the top of the file and got the following error:

`error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int` for the line `typedef SOCKET curl_socket_t;` in `curl.h`.

At the top of `curl.h` I saw that the following preprocessor macros prevent the inclusion of `winsock2.h` which defines `SOCKET`:

```
#if !(defined(_WINSOCKAPI_) || defined(_WINSOCK_H) || \
      defined(__LWIP_OPT_H__) || defined(LWIP_HDR_OPT_H))
/* The check above prevents the winsock2 inclusion if winsock.h already was
   included, since they can't co-exist without problems */
    #include <winsock2.h>
    #include <ws2tcpip.h>
#endif
```

Removing the `defined(_WINSOCKAPI_)` condition restores the statement and everything compiles fine, meaning that somewhere `winsock.h` is included and that on UWP it does not defined `SOCKET`.

Indeed, looking at `winsock.h` I can see that the `typedef` which defines `SOCKET` is wrapped with

```
#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP)
```

which does not hold for a universal app.

However, in `winsock2.h` there’s an equivalent `typedef` for `SOCKET` which is not dropped by the preprocessor.

Adding `#include <winsock2.h>` before the `#include <curl\curl.h>` statement makes everything work, but I suspect this is not the best way to solve this issue.

So my question is, is this the proper way to use curl on UWP or has anyone found a better solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirmed that `winsock.h` is being included by the following include chain: `pch.h > collection.h > agile.h > wrl\client.h > unknwn.h > rpc.h > windows.h > winsock.h`. `pch.h` is generated by Visual Studio, and is part of the Universal blank app template.

My workaround is not ideal because this will get `winsock.h` and `winsock2.h` both included, and the comment in `curl.h` says they can't co-exist.

However, I did find that in `windows.h`, the inclusion of `winsock.h` is wrapped with `#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`, i.e., I can prevent `winsock.h` from being included by adding the `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` define.

I tried it and successfully issued a simple https request from a UWP app.

So to summarize - when using curl in a UWP app, you must add the preprocessor definition `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally it should be no problem to include <winsock2.h> before <curl/curl.h>. But you're also right that it should work without that, because curl.h should include that file if necessary. 
As it does not in your case, _WINSOCKAPI_ must be defined somewhere else. Perhaps it's defined in the preprocessor area of the project settings, i.e. it is provided via /D compiler flag. Did you already look there? Also look at the compiler command line, that is used to compile your file, is there a flag that defines _WINSOCKAPI_?

BTW, the reason why curl includes <winsock2.h> conditionally is as follows: Windows has two different socket libraries, winsock and winsock2 (which is to prefer). Both cannot coexistent with each other. 
If you need to use winsock instead of winsock2 for some reason you may include <winsock.h> before <curl/curl.h>, and it will work as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I compiled the project with /showincludes and I found that `winsock.h` gets included implicitly by the pch.h and that's where the `_WINSOCKAPI_` definition comes from.
As I mentioned in my question, having `winsock.h` included does not work well in UWP, because there's a preprocessor instruction that excludes the needed typedef of `SOCKET`.